# Converting semicolon column value to rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I could see there are answers in the blog, but still I need slight modification in the below query. For example in my scenario I have Start date and End date columns and I need to filter my columns with those columns.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Start, [End],
    Organizer,
    DisplayTo,
    City As Location,
    LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]', 'varchar(max)'))) AS test
FROM
    (SELECT 
         Start, [End], Organizer, DisplayTo, City,
         CAST('<M>' + REPLACE(Location,';','</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS x
     FROM  
         testdata.dbo.RawData_load 
     WHERE
         Start > GETDATE()) t
CROSS APPLY 
    x.nodes('/M') m(n)
```

When I tried the above part, I get an error:

> XML parsing illegal character.

Can someone please let me know if there are any alternatives for the above query?

Thanks,
Sj

Comment: Why `mysql` tag if you ask for `SQL-Server`?

Comment: ok then please provide only for SQL server

Comment: Could you, please, provide some sample data and expected results?

Comment: select start,[end],location from testdata  - Sample query ---query results-- 
start end location
2015-07-09 16:30:00.000 2015-07-09 17:00:00.000 Santiago - Duao; Santiago - Rapa Nui; Santiago - San Pedro de Atacama; Santiago - Torres del Paine; Santiago - Anakena
2015-07-09 16:30:00.000 2015-07-09 17:00:00.000 Santiago - Duao; Santiago - Rapa Nui; Santiago - San Pedro de Atacama; Santiago - Torres del Paine; Santiago - Anakena

Comment: Hi,Since we have more than 2million records when we use the above query it says xml parsing error